# Is it possible to use <time> HTML tag to format SQL data

Tags: php, html, mysql

Is it possible to use `<time>` HTML tag to format SQL data? for example:

```
'<time datetime="8:30">".$row['time']."</time>'
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by format SQL data?

Comment: No.  You should format the time with PHP or Javascript.  There is no reason at all to attempt to rely on an HTML tag.

Comment: AFAIK, the time tag does absolutely nothing in terms of formatting, but jQuery can be used to grab all time tags and format them after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

You should really go with something simple, because you have access to PHP anyway

```
<?php
echo strtotime($row['time'])
?>
```

That is a more correct way.  Or more importantly, a more flexible way.

Comment: Depending on the stack, OP might not want to let php have concern on the presentation layer.  In which case he could use javascript or a library like moment.js.